# Can I use `.phtml` instead of `.php`

Tags: php

I want to use `.php` extension for php that have a logic like `functions.php`, and for a html template file `.phtml`.

Is there way to use `.phtml` instead of `.php` extension? For example, `sidepar.phtml`, `page.phtml` and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to echo all of the above comments & say it's not a good practice to get into. You might want to borrow a convention from the PHPTemplate library used in Drupal and call your files `something.tpl.php`. That way it's still a `.php` file, but you have an extra extension showing it's a template.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such ability. Even more I wouldn't recommend you to use `.phtml` extensions. Why? Because they won't be interpreted as PHP files if you open them directly in the browser (for instance `http://mysite.com/wp-content/theme/mytheme/single.phtml`).

So the best practice and good habit is to use `.php` extension for your templates.

Comment: As far as I know, interpretation of file depends on server setting that I can change myself. But if it is good practice to use `.php` in wordpress community, I'd use `.php` extension. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Yes, it is OK if you do it for yourself. But if you will share your theme, then you can't be confident in other people hosting environments.

Comment: I'd even go further, @EugeneManuilov I dont think it is a good practice within WordPress development. Because you start doing it for *private use code* and soon enough you will be coding for a customer or contributing to a project with these acquired routine, that doesn't fit the community best practices for WP :)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with .htaccess files by adding the line

```
AddHandler php-cgi .phtml
```

File Handling is actually done by your server and not php itself, so yes you can change the extensions to something custom.

However as stated in a comment. I would only do this if you are not going to share your themes as most people wouldn't be able to use it.